# Как перевести данные из input в google?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-search

Есть `<input type="search">` и `<input type="button>`. При нажатии на button. Данные из input нужно открыть в google. Как можно это реализовать на javascript?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уииии: `https://www.google.ru/search?q=YourRequestHere`.

Comment: Зачем такие заморочки? добавь в GET переменную

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('#run').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  let query = document.querySelector('#query').value;
  
  if(query)
    window.location = `https://www.google.ru/search?q=${query}`;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='query' /> | <input type='button' id='run' value='Google it!' />
```